# Parse String into a DateTime Object in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, c#-4.0, datetime

I am trying to Parse a String date and time into a single .NET DateTime object. I have the following code:

```
string dtObjFormat = "dd MMM YYYY HH:mm";
string mydatetimemash = e.Date + " " + e.Time; // this becomes 25 May 2013 10:30
DateTime dt;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(mydatetimemash, dtObjFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
} else 
{
    dt = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

But the TryParseExact always returns false for me, meaning the Parse fails. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think your Y's need to be lower case.

Comment: @JMK please post as Answer, so that I mark it as Answer. You were right! :)

Comment: @JKM I bet it's just test code; in the real code he will be parsing real dates.

Comment: I'm printing to the Console for debugging purposes. I have other things that I want to do with the DateTime object ;)

Comment: Surely @JMK gave the right answer. `DateTime.TryParseExact("25 May 2013 10:30", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)` works fine, whereas the variant with `"YYYY"` doesn't work.

Comment: The Object was a String that represents a date, So it is a String object that I got from an XML file that I am parsing. Post it as Answer already! :P

Comment: @JMK I don't know what type `e` was. It must be some type with instance properties (fields) `Date` and `Time`. The `System.DateTime` struct has a property `TimeOfDay` but no `Time`, so `e` wasn't a `DateTime`. Edit: Also, if `e` where a `DateTime`, saying `e.Date + " "` would already give a midnight time-of-day part, then the final string would get two time-of-day parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Y's need to be lower case, like so:

```
string dtObjFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm";
string mydatetimemash = e.Date + " " + e.Time; // this becomes 25 May 2013 10:30
DateTime dt;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(mydatetimemash, dtObjFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
} else 
{
    dt = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

Comment: Haha finally :D Thank You very much JMK. ^_^